# Xamarin Forms conditonal formatting based on data with DataTrigger

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a chat application in Xamarin Forms and I am trying to add conditional formatting depending on whether it is an incoming or outgoing message.

This is my XAML:

```
               <Frame 
                    Margin="1"
                    Padding="0"
                    x:Name="FrameRef"
                    x:DataType="model:ChatMessage">
                    <Frame 
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="7"
                        BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                        HasShadow="false"
                        Margin="10,10,80,0">
                        <Frame.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                TargetType="Frame"
                                Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference FrameRef}, Path=x:DataType.From}" Value="+1456456456">
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Frame.Triggers>
```

When I use Path="Margin" and Value="1" it works.

I am now trying to make it work with the Path being x:DataType="model:ChatMessage" and checking the 'from'-field (indicating if the message was incoming or outgoing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the [Data Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.DataTrigger?view=xamarin-forms) is quite right for this application, since you're really depending on a data type and not really the content per se of another field. From the documentation:

> The DataTrigger class is suitable for checking values on other controls, as well as any property on the control to which it has been added.

What you probably want instead is a Value Converter that handles locating a StaticResource and applying a style for you based on the message type. Full Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters).

On your XAML element, you'd do something like this:

```
<Frame Style="{Binding foo, Converter={StaticResource FooToStyleConverter}}"/>
```

Your converter would work something like this:

```cs
public class FooToStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var someValue = (DataTye)value; // Convert 'object' to whatever type you are expecting

        // evaluate the converted value
        if (someValue.From != null && someValue.From == Enum.SomeoneElse)
            return (Style)App.Current.Resources["StyleReceived"]; // return the desired style indicating the message is from someone else

        return (Style)App.Current.Resources["StyleSent"]; // return a style indicating the message is from the sender
    }
    
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Usually unused, but inverse the above logic if needed
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Lastly, set up your converter as a Static Resource in App.xaml (or as a local resource on the page) so your page can properly reference it

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingDemos">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
              <local:FooToStyleConverter x:Key="FooToStyleConverter" />
              ....
```